# Why the UI-Bootstrap popover does not appear when inside an ngIf?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, popover, angular-ng-if

The code says it all.
I am aware that ngIf will remove or clone element from/to the DOM, but I don't see why the popover directive is affected (popover-is-open).
Plunker : https://plnkr.co/edit/eym62cur2cg1qyZzpQaf?p=preview

```
<div>
    <input type="text" 
      uib-popover="This one will appear" 
      popover-placement="right"     
      popover-is-open={{true}}
    />
</div>

<div  ng-if="true">
    <input type="text" 
      uib-popover="This one will not appear because of ngIf even if true" 
      popover-placement="right"     
      popover-is-open={{true}}
      placeholder="Why the ngIf prevent the popover to appear ??"
    />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have answer in your own question. Since you already know that `ng-if` will remove DOM element, use `ng-show` to solve your issue.

Comment: I know that. I would like to understand why. Is it a bug ?

Comment: As per my understanding it's not a bug. Since it adds the element dynamically after evaluating the ng-if, I think pop-over would have been initialized by that time. Since ng-show hides/shows (but element is already present in the html), pop-over will bind to it no matter what. Thats why it does not show when you use ng-if. Hope this makes sense.